# If two sheaves have same stalks everywhere, then two sheaves are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This is a problem of Tennison Sheaf Theory Problem 2.1

"Let $I=[0,1]\subset R$, Show there is a unique(up to isomorphism) sheaf of abelian groups $F$ on $I$ with stalks:$F_0=F_1=Z, F_x=\{0\}$ for $x\in I-\{0,1\}$"

This is basically constructed from patching two skyscraper sheaves. Consider $F(U)=Z$, for either $0$ or $1\in U$,  and $F(U)=0$, for anything else. This gives rise to $F$.

1. I think the problem can be simplified to consider non-trivial stalk at only 1 point and generalized to consider any number of closed points that are not limit points of each other.
2. If my proof is correct, then the statement can be relaxed to the following statement which should be wrong for sure.

Given any two sheaves $S,S'$ over $X$, if for all $x\in X$, $S_x= S'_x$, then $S\cong S'$.

Let $\Gamma(-,F)$ be the functor of sheaf of sections of sheaf space $(F,p,X)$ where $p:F\to X$. Let $L$ be the functor forming sheaf space $(LP,\pi, X)$ from presheaf $P$ where $\pi:LP\to X$ by projection.

It is clear that $\Gamma(-,LS)\cong S$ if $S$ is a sheaf. Let $S'$ be another sheaf over $X$ with same stalks as those of $S$. So we know $LS=LS'$ as $LS$ is disjoint union of all stalks. So $\Gamma(-,LS)=\Gamma(-,LS')$. So I conclude that $S\cong\Gamma(-,LS)=\Gamma(-,LS')\cong S'$ where the middle is just equality. So $S\cong S'$.

It seems that I can even say $LS\cong LS'$ as sheaf space isomorphism resulting in $\Gamma(-,LS)\cong\Gamma(-,LS')$. It is known that without prescribing the morphism $S\to S'$, even if the stalks are isomorphic, we are not guaranteed that $S\cong S'$.

3. I am certain I have done something very wrong here. It would be kind that someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: No, certainly not. For example, locally constant sheaves on a sufficiently nice space $X$ correspond to covering spaces, with stalks corresponding to fibers. If $X$ is connected then the locally constant sheaves with stalks isomorphic to a finite set of size $n$ are classified by actions of $\pi_1(X)$ on sets of size $n$.

Comment: The subsets of "coherent" functions in $\prod_{x\in U} S_x$ or $U \to \bigsqcup_{x\in U} S_x$, depending on the definition, are going to be different based on the presheaf structures of $S$ or $S'$.

Comment: By the way, what you've defined for the original problem isn't a sheaf, only a presheaf - for example, the sections $0 \in F([0, \frac{2}{3}))$ and $1 \in F((\frac{1}{3}, 1])$ trivially agree on the overlap, but they don't glue to a section on the union.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Maybe this is a dumb question. The zero sheaf is a sheaf with all stalks trivial. This implies sheaf of sections should not be trivial in this case. However, I cannot have any non-trivial sections with value distinct from 0 at 0 and 1. The discreteness of the fiber implies that this should be 0 everywhere as a section on any open set containing 0 or 1 vanishes at any points other than 0 and 1. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: @user45765 Not quite sure what exactly you're asking here...  If all stalks of a sheaf of abelian groups, say, are the trivial group, then certainly that determines the sheaf uniquely to be the zero sheaf.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think I need $F([0,1])=\{0\}$ and everything else are the same as I described in the post. For your counter-example, $0\in F([0,\frac{2}{3}))$ and $1\in F((\frac{1}{3},1])$, they can be glued together as it is disconnected. The global section will be trivial irregardless.